# How long does it take for Vit D medications to show effect?

Tags: vitamin-d

Being diagnosed with severe vitamin D deficiency, I am on a high dosage (50k IU per week) for the past 2 months. I have also been getting regular sun exposure. 
But my weakness and other problems which show because of the deficiency have become worse (although my levels are rising as per the blood work).

A few people said that the medications will make things worse before it gets better.

Is this true? I have been trying to read a lot about this and haven't come across anything stating this. Does anyone know if this is true and what is the scientific reason?